# wrong html output from the javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wrote a script for populating a selectbox with a bunch of options.

Initially the `data` is in the form of string of a format "key=value;key2=value2;etc...":

```
//split the string to distinguish between different options to populate a selectbox with
var values = data.split(';');
//reset the length of the selectbox to be populated
document.getElementById(child).options.length = 0;
//create first default option
document.getElementById(child).options[0] = new Option('all', '0');
for(var i = 0; i < values.length; i++){
    //check for and remove unnecessary characters
    values[i].replace(/\s+/g, '');
    //split the option to get the key and value separately
    var options = values[i].split('=');
    if(!isEmpty(options[0]) && !isEmpty(options[1])){
        //insert a new element to the selectbox
        document.getElementById(child).options[i+1] = new Option(options[1], options[0]);
    }
}
```

The example above populates a selectbox with the given html output:

```
<option value="0">all</option>
<option value=" 
7">Bermuda</option>
<option value="10">British Virgin Islands</option>
<option value="15">Cayman Islands</option>
<option value="42">Jamaica</option>
<option value="74">St. Lucia</option>
<option value="79">Trinidad Tobago</option>
```

As you can notice above the second option in the selectbox has a corrupted string value. I need to fix that value because because of that cake cannot save this value properly.

If you have any other questions please ask.

Comment: Why is it corrupted? Isn't the value Bermuda?

Comment: @neo: The line is broken (`\n`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to trim values:

```
document.getElementById(child).options[i+1] = new Option(
   options[1].replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, ''), 
   options[0].replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '')
);
```

or if you are using jquery:

```
document.getElementById(child).options[i+1] = new Option(
   $.trim(options[1]), 
   $.trim(options[0])
);
```

also you should look close on this fragment:

```
values[i].replace(/\s+/g, '');
```

because probably it doesn't do what you want. First, it removes all whitespaces from string so "New York City" will become "NewYorkCity". Next thing is that `replace` method returns new string so your code will take no effect. It should be:

```
values[i] = values[i].replace(/\s+/g, '');
```